# Bitcoin daemon consuming too much internet data

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind

I recently started Blockchain and crypto. I started with ethereum and now on bitcoin. Today I run bitcoin daemon and while i was figuring out some other api related stuff related to bitcoin-cli, I lost about 110gb of data in just like 4 or 5 or max 6 hours.

I just have 4gb left for the entire month. My job is to just create a node for bitcoin and check if data can be retreived from those nodes using curl.

I am using ubuntu20 mint. If there is any config or something i can do about it.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How much data do you think is fair for the global financial system to use?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just got the solution, this is happening because I was trying to sync a bitcoin node that will sync around 400GB of data(approx) as mentioned by @David. So the solution to it was to make my bitcoin node, a test node it can be done by either making the testnet=1 or regtest=1. After this my bitcoin.conf file looks like this

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
testnet=1
[test]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=18332
```

or if you want to use regtest then

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=Password
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
regtest=1
[regtest]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=18443
```

Make sure you use only one(either regtest or testnode). More details about options in config file can be found [here](https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line/blob/master/04_4__Interlude_Using_Curl.md).

Answer (score -3):

It is not advisable to synch a bitcoin daemon on a node with limited bandwidth. The node has to load the entire history of the blockchain in order to synchronize with it. That's around 400GB or so these days. You can slow it down, but it will take *much* longer to be functional, likely several months.

Comment: Outgoing bandwidth may be consumed _after_ the blockchain was downloaded also.

Comment: While the original question isn't clear, it's almost certainly nearly all inbound data given the statement that he "recently started".

Comment: The thing is I want to curl into bitcoind and get the user data like walletinfo blockchaininfo etc and for that I dont need to sync the main node of the bitcoin I found the solution for this that is by specifying either testnet=1 or regtest=1 in the conf file hence preventing the entire node to sync and just fetch the required details.

Thanks for help